# Speeding up a function with Parallel.For

Tags: vb.net, performance, loops, parallel.for

I have written this function and I am trying to speed it up using `Parallel.For` or otherwise. However, when I replace one of the loops with a `Parallel.For`, it gives the wrong results.

```
Public Function InverseFromUpperTriangular(U As Matrix) As Matrix
    Dim n As Integer = U.RowCount
    Dim Y As Matrix = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Matrix.Build.Dense(n, n)
    Dim S As Matrix = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Matrix.Build.Dense(n, n)
    For j = n - 1 To 0 Step -1
        S(j, j) = 1.0 / U(j, j)
        For i = j To 0 Step -1
            Y(i, j) = (S(i, j) - U.Row(i).SubVector(i, n - i) * Y.Column(j).SubVector(i, n - i)) / U(i, i)
            Y(j, i) = Y(i, j)
        Next
    Next
    Return Y
End Function
```

**EDIT**

This is my function with the `Parallel.For`

```
Public Function InverseFromUpperTriangular(U As Matrix) As Matrix
    Dim n As Integer = U.RowCount
    Dim Y As Matrix = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Matrix.Build.Dense(n, n)
    Dim S As Matrix = MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Matrix.Build.Dense(n, n)

    Parallel.For(0, n, Sub(ii)
                           Dim j = n - 1 - ii
                           S(j, j) = 1.0 / U(j, j)
                           For i = j To 0 Step -1
                               Y(i, j) = (S(i, j) - U.Row(i).SubVector(i, n - i) * Y.Column(j).SubVector(i, n - i)) / U(i, i)
                               Y(j, i) = Y(i, j)
                           Next
                       End Sub)

    Return Y
End Function
```

Comment: C# or VB.Net? Away from that, google is not pornographic, you can find tons of examples. Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What did the code for your parallel version look like?

Comment: I'm not that well versed in linear algebra or matrices, so there may be subtleties I'm missing, but the loop contents seem to be dependent on each other (lots of shared variables, especially `S`, and `Y`). It doesn't look parallelizable  to me.

Comment: This appears to be simple maths. Computers are very fast at doing maths. Threads are slow to create. So doing simple maths on multiple threads is slow. Stick to one thread unless your matrices are hundreds or maybe thousands of elements per row and column.

Comment: Thanks Bradley, i have added my 'Parallel.For' code now. I feel like the different threads are creating problems but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The different threads are *definitely* causing your problems. The contents of `S` will be both read from, and written to, by different threads at unpredictable times.  You will never be sure what state `S` is in as each threads accesses it.  This implementation doesn't look like it can be made parallel.  I don't know enough about matrix math to know if there are alternate implementations that *could* be made parallel though.

Comment: Seems like you are doing things in your loop that aren't needed since you erase previously calculated fields when setting to Y. Since you expected it to be in a specific order, the parallel doesn't guarantee the order of execution.

Comment: Thanks Guys! This makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is definitely not thread safe.  One of the requirements for `Parallel.For` (and most `Parallel` methods) is that each step must be independent.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx):

> It's easy to change a sequential loop into a parallel loop. However,
>   it's also easy to use a parallel loop when you shouldn't. This is
>   because it can be hard to tell if the steps are actually independent
>   of each other. It takes practice to learn how to recognize when one
>   step is dependent on another step. Sometimes, using this pattern on a
>   loop with dependent steps causes the program to behave in a completely
>   unexpected way, and perhaps to stop responding. Other times, it
>   introduces a subtle bug that only appears once in a million runs. In
>   other words, the word "independent" is a key part of the definition of
>   this pattern, and one that this chapter explains in detail.

You have 2 outer variables, `Y`, and `S`, that are both read from, and written to, within the loop.  Each thread of the `For` is accessing those variables at unknown, and unpredictable times.  There may even be times when those variables are accesses simultaneously by 2 threads at the exact same time from different cores.  There is no way for you to know the state that `S` and `Y` are in at each iteration of the loop.

I don't know enough about matrix math to know if there is another implementation of what you are trying to do that *could* be made thread safe, but the one you have will definitely not work.